# Pymacs helper did not start after 30 seconds

Tags: python, emacs, ropemacs, pymacs

I've seen other questions on this, but none of them were actually answered, and none of them are quite my issue.

I have a new system, emacs 23.1, Centos 6.2 (I think). I downloaded the newest pymacs and installed it. However, I'm getting:

```
error: Pymacs helper did not start within 30 seconds
```

This is with a .emacs and .bashrc that have always worked before. Also, it appears that when I run from gnome, it does find the pymacs helper (but ropemacs doesn't run), but in KDE (which is what I'm actually trying to use) It gives the pymacs helper error.

EDITING because I found this question when I had it again months later.

Now, I am getting the pymacs helper error in gnome too. I've commented out  the line:

```
(autoload 'python-mode "python-mode" "Python editing mode" )
```

But that doesn't seem to help. This is with the newest pymacs.

Comment: Hi! Can you please try to install according to [these instructions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22496541/596361) and see if it works?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK that error occurs if an older pymacs.el gets loaded. Check if such a thing might be in your path still.

In case the trouble persists, get Pymacs inlined with python-mode:

bzr branch lp:python-mode/components-python-mode

Answer (score 0):

The author of `Pymacs` states that it is a problem related to an old version of `python-mode.el` which loads its own copy of `Pymacs`. He proposes two different solutions (see [here](https://github.com/pinard/Pymacs#python-modeel-difficulty)):

*1)* Comment out the `python-mode` initialisation (I guess `pymacs` loads it then)
*2)* Set the variable `py-load-pymacs-p` to `nil`

If I recall correctly the second fix doesn't work for my emacs but the first one does. Also it might be necessary to update your version of `Pymacs`, as far as I know it is developed on github now, thus you can use the version found in the above repo.

Comment: in extension of what was said: if Pymacs is installed separately, remove the pymacs.el delivered with (older) python-mode.el, because that will be in your path and disturb maybe

Comment: Where do I find the python-mode initialization? I don't seem to have a python-mode.el or I don't know where to find it. It is not in my .emacs.d/ directory.